# loop command not running on correct number of inputs in R

Tags: r, loops

I am reading in a list of 10 dataframes in to R

And then in to a function to extract data from an online server

```
library(TwoSampleMR)
library(tidyr)
my_files <- list.files(pattern = "*_gws.txt")
my_data <- lapply(my_files, read.table)
model <- lapply(my_data, function(x){extract_outcome_data(snps = (lapply(my_data, "[[",4)), outcomes = c('outcome1','outcome2','outcome2'))})
```

It all runs fine, however the output is not as expected. It only gives me the results for the first 10 extractions from the column #4.

```
Extracting data for 10 SNP(s) from 1 GWAS(s)
Extracting data for 10 SNP(s) from 1 GWAS(s)
Extracting data for 10 SNP(s) from 1 GWAS(s)
```

I think this is because there are 10 dataframes, so it is confusing the N of dataframes with the N of observations - each dataframe has between 2000 and 4000 rows and I want the function to run on those so I expect around these N on the return.

How can I amend this accordingly?
Thanks

Comment: Should it be: `model <- lapply(my_data, function(x){extract_outcome_data(snps = (lapply(x, "[[",4)), outcomes = c('outcome1','outcome2','outcome2'))})` instead?

Comment: So this changes the output, but to a different N [between 7-9 extractions, not 10]. So I think this is working on another row? But the row I want definitely is row 4, and has 1000s of unique obs. Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: The result of `lapply(mydata, "[[", 4)` will be a list where each element is the fourth column from one element of `mydata`.  If you did what I suggested the sup input to the `extract_outcome_data()` function would be in turn, the fourth column from each dataset.  I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.  Posting some example data might help.